# How do we configure symfony 1.4 to use it with Varnish?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, symfony-1.4, varnish

I had a huge load on my servers yesterday, and, even if I worked on optimizing the performances before (I had a similar problem about 2 months ago), my servers couldn't handle the load (I have a service which had about 50 account creations per minute).

Finally, my servers handled the load because I changed the instances : I am on Amazon EC2, and I was using a load balancer with 20 micro instances. It was not enough. I finally changed to 10 large instances, and that was OK.
But, you know, large instances are kinda expensive, and I can't afford to have so much large instances (now, because there is less load, I have "only" 5 large instances running, but it is also too much).

So, I am still working on the optimization and the server configuration, but I am stuck on a point.

So far, I am using symfony with memcached. It works fine, everything that should be cached is cached, etc.

Now, I want to add a Varnish in front of my apache web server.

I did so, and I configured it - I think - well, and it is running now. The problem is that there is no hit on the cache.

From what I saw, the problem is that the HTTP headers sent by symfony are not set correctly.
For example, for a cached request, I have the following headers :

```
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Pragma: no-cache
```

The module is correctly configured to use cache, etc., but I just can't find where I can set the correct HTTP headers. I know how to set a cache header in symfony for a specific action, but clearly, I don't want to do it on every action (by the way, even if I did that, I think that this is not the right way).

So I'm asking how can I use Varnish with symfony 1.4
From what I saw, there are two possibilities :

- I set correctly the HTTP headers sent by symfony
- I configure Varnish to handle correctly the default HTTP headers sent by symfony

Do you know how can I fix either one of the problems ?

Thanks,

N.B. : I am on Varnish3

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I too will be using varnish with symfony 1.4 soon. I'll be interested in reading the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found on my own how to resolve my problem, so I'm going to share how I did it :

To start, you should know that symfony creates automatically a PHP session every time a page is called. So, what I did was to deactivate that default behaviour. To do so, I added on the factories.yml a storage factory (the default one : sfSessionStorage) with the **auto_start** parameter set to **false**:

```
storage:
  class: sfSessionStorage
  param:
    auto_start: false
```

Then, I created a filter to handle the http headers :

I firstly added it to the filters.yml file

```
http_header:
  class: myHttpHeaderFilter
```

And then I added a myHttpHeaderFilter.php class on the lib folder, where I handled all the headers I wanted. For example :

```
class myHttpHeaderFilter extends sfFilter
{
    public function execute($filterChain)
    {
      //execute the next filter in the chain
      $filterChain->execute();
      //code after here runs after action

      // Filters don't have direct access to the request and user objects.
      // You will need to use the context object to get them
      $request = $this->getContext()->getRequest();
      $path = $request->getPathInfo();

      if (substr($path, 0, 5) == "/foo") // We cache only some of the /foo requests
      {
          if (strstr($path, "bar")) // We cache the request containing bar during half an hour hour
              $this->getContext()->getResponse()->addCacheControlHttpHeader('max-age=1800');
          else // All the other requests are cached during 24 hours
          {
              $this->getContext()->getResponse()->addCacheControlHttpHeader('max-age=86400');
          }
      }
      else // The other requests are not cached
          $this->getContext()->getResponse()->addCacheControlHttpHeader('no-cache, no-store');
    }
}
```

And that was it !

I also modified the vcl_recv on the server side, to ensure that all requests that not need to be cached are not (in theory, it is not mandatory to do so, because I handled it on symfony, it is just a "double-check").

```
sub vcl_recv {
     if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
         /* Not cacheable by default */
         return (pass);
     }

     if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
         return (pass);
     }

     if (req.url ~ "/user") /* Requests containing user data are never cached */
        {
                return (pass);
        }

     return (lookup);
}
```

Comment: Hi, how did you manage the CSRF tokens with Varnish? We have a login form on each page (on a modal) and we want to use Varnish, but we are not sure how to avoid having problems. thanks!